# How safe is this swap w/o pushing registers?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

I'm very new to Assembly and the code below is supposed to swap two integers via two different functions: first using `swap_c` and then using `swap_asm`.

However, I doubt, whether I need to `push` (I mean save) each value of registers before assembly code and `pop` them later (just before returning to `main`). In other words, will the CPU get mad at me if I return different register content (not the crucial ones like `ebp` or `esp`; but, just `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` & `edx`) after running `swap_asm` function? Is it better to uncomment the lines in the assembly part?

This code runs OK for me and I managed to reduce the 27 lines of assembled `C` code down to 7 Assembly lines.

p.s.: System is Windows 10, VS-2013 Express.

`main.c` part

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void swap_asm(int *x, int *y);

void swap_c(int *a, int *b) {
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = 3, y = 5;
    printf("before swap    => x = %d     y = %d\n\n", x, y);

    swap_c(&x, &y);
    printf("after swap_c   => x = %d     y = %d\n\n", x, y);

    swap_asm(&x, &y);
    printf("after swap_asm => x = %d     y = %d\n\n", x, y);

    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

`assembly.asm` part

```
 .686
.model flat, c
.stack 100h
.data

.code
swap_asm proc
    ; push eax
    ; push ebx
    ; push ecx
    ; push edx
    mov eax, [esp] + 4  ; get address of "x" stored in stack into eax
    mov ebx, [esp] + 8  ; get address of "y" stored in stack into ebx
    mov ecx, [eax]      ; get value of "x" from address stored in [eax] into ecx
    mov edx, [ebx]      ; get value of "y" from address stored in [ebx] into edx
    mov [eax], edx      ; store value in edx into address stored in [eax]
    mov [ebx], ecx      ; store value in ecx into address stored in [ebx]
    ; pop edx
    ; pop ecx
    ; pop ebx
    ; pop eax
    ret
swap_asm endp
end
```

Comment: You can use the dedicated [`xchg`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_328.html) instruction

Comment: if you need atomic then use atomic

Comment: @anatolyg `xchg` with a memory operand introduces a bus lock which is something you probably don't want.

Comment: Let me guess, the "27 lines" of compiler output was without optimization?  Your `swap_c` [compiles to 9 asm instructions with `gcc -O3 -m32`](http://goo.gl/ciYo3V).  Compiling for 64bit, it's only 5 instructions.  (enough scratch registers, and args already in registers).  Beating the compiler is only interesting if you tell it to try to optimize :P

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I'm using VS-2013; so, I compile my C code on Microsoft c++ compiler with `/TC` directive. Though I've selected *full optimization*, I couldn't come up with less than 26 lines of assembly code. Either I'm doing something wrong (when compiling) or that's some kind of an extra talent that gcc have.

Comment: @merkez3110: it's probably all boilerplate anti-stack-overflow code.  You're only counting instructions, not directives, labels, and comments, right?  Can you post the compiler output somewhere?  Because 26 instructions sounds pretty ridiculous.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Here is my "main.asm" output of "main.c"; `swap_c` starts at line ~200. https://gist.github.com/merkez3110/111ca33396daa1f62cf4

Comment: @merkez3110: there's no way that's optimized code.  It stores `t` on the stack, and it reloads the pointers from the stack multiple times each.  The `rep stosd` boilersplate looks like it's writing some kind of magic value to 204 bytes of stack space that the function reserves for no apparent reason. [According to the docs, `/TC` means compile as C (not C++).  `/Ox` enables full optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx).  The comments in your asm output say it was compiled with `/Od` (disable optimization).

Comment: @PeterCordes: You were right. I set the compiler for maximum optimization but then checked the "inherit from parent" tick-box. So, the compiler didn't really optimize at all. After correcting things, I came up with 7 lines of assembly code (though, still it seems a little weird to me): https://gist.github.com/merkez3110/d2d5e8a1632b6f62f090

Comment: @merkez3110 Looks like the compiler chose a different calling convention, possibly fastcall. Strange...

Comment: @merkez3110: Apparently the default ABI that MSVC in 32bit mode passes some args in registers.  [Probably `__vectorcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dn375768.aspx).  It may only do this as part of whole-program optimization, but hopefully 32bit code in general isn't quite as bad as I thought on Windows (32bit is still obsolete; the old stack-args ABI is/was only one of its problems).   The pointer arguments are obviously in `edx` and `ecx`.  It has to save/restore `esi` because it can't avoid having both pointers and both values registers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, this depends on the calling convention of the system you are working on. The *calling convention* specifies how to call functions. Generally, it says where to put the arguments and what registers must be preserved by the called function.

On i386 Windows with the cdecl calling convention (which is the one you probably use), you can freely overwrite the `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` registers. The `ebx` register must be preserved. While your code appears to work, it mysteriously fails when a function starts to depend on `ebx` being preserved, so better save and restore it.

Comment: I'm aware that I have to push `ecx` before calling `swap_asm`, in case `swap_asm` is called within a loop; but I didn't get the reason for `ebx`. Can you explain it a little? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @merkez3110 Registers are grouped into two classes with respect to function calls: *caller saved registers* like `ecx` must be preserved by the caller if the caller wishes to preserves them and can be freely overwritten by the callee. *Callee saved registers* like `ebx` must be preserved by the callee, the caller may assume that the register has the same value after the function call it had before. Does that answer your question?

Comment: From what I've got so far: (1) `ecx` is **caller saved**; feel free to overwrite; (2) `ebx` is **callee saved**; it's better to return the original value received from caller. Thank you again.

Comment: @merkez3110 Yeah, you got that right. See the Wikipedia article on [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for more details.

Comment: @merkez3110: see [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for many good links, including calling-convention / ABI beginner-stuff and reference docs.